# How to evaluate the URL Parameter value in JS Script in paw

Tags: paw-app

I need to create a sign method in JS Parameter. I use some variables like Environment Variable or the Secure Variable in some parameter, and in the sign parameter I need to get the evaluated value of them, but I got undefined. Is there a way to get the evaluated parameter's value?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, take the [tour], and read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to get a specific URL parameter (evaluated as a string):

```js
var value = request.getUrlParameterByName('myParam'); // string
```

If you'd like to get a `DynamicString` instead, you may use:

```js
var value = request.getUrlParameterByName('myParam', true); // DynamicString
return value.getEvaluatedString(); // string
```

You may also get all URL parameters as a JavaScript object (key-values):

```js
var params = request.getUrlParameters(); // object
return params['myParam']; // string
```

You can get all URL parameters as a JavaScript object where values are `DynamicString` objects:

```js
var params = request.getUrlParameters(true); // object
var value = value['myParam']; // DynamicString
return value.getEvaluatedString(); // string
```

I hope it helps!